# Duplicate data or Relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, denormalization

Given two tables:

#### Product

```
int    id
int    operator_id
string name
string description
int    price
```

#### Operator

```
int    id
string logo_path
string tos_path
int    tax_number
```

I need to call multiple `Product` a few times. Most of the times I call a `Product`, I need to get the `Operator`'s name and logo.

I know that we should avoid duplicating data when possible, and be using more elegant ways to bind data, but in this case, isn't it more efficient to put `int operator_name` and `int operator_logo` into `Product` table instead of calling at each request, one more request to find the `Operator`?

Or is it the really point of relationships, DBs being OK with dealing with one more request instead of duplicating the data?

A bit beginner into optimization and not really knowing what and where to search into to find answers, thanks for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your tables are defined like this (by converting your descriptions to SQL Data Definition Language - DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE operator
(
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    logo_path varchar(255),
    tos_path varchar(255),
    tax_number integer
) ;

CREATE TABLE product
(
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    operator_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES operator(id),  /* This is actually ignored by MySQL, but not by "well-behaved" databases */
    name varchar(100),
    description varchar(255),
    price decimal(12,2)
) ;
```

Let's put some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO 
    operator
    (id, logo_path, tos_path, tax_number)
VALUES
    (1000, '/path/to/logo/1000', '/path/to/tos/1000', 1234),
    (1001, '/path/to/logo/1001', '/path/to/tos/1001', 5678) 
;

INSERT INTO
    product
    (id, operator_id, name, description, price)
VALUES
    (1, 1000, 'Product Name', 'Product Description', 1234.56),
    (2, 1001, 'Product 2', 'Description 2', 2345.67)
;
```

... and now we can perform a `SELECT` with a [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT
    product.id, product.name, product.price, operator.logo_path,
    operator.tos_path, operator.tax_number
FROM
    product
    JOIN operator ON operator.id = product.operator_id ;
```

This is the result you would get, you retrieve the data from both `product` and `operator` with just one query. The database will handle how to fetch it from the tables. One of the objectives of *relational* databases is to just *let them do this kind of things*

```
id | name         |   price | logo_path          | tos_path          | tax_number
-: | :----------- | ------: | :----------------- | :---------------- | ---------:
 1 | Product Name | 1234.56 | /path/to/logo/1000 | /path/to/tos/1000 |       1234
 2 | Product 2    | 2345.67 | /path/to/logo/1001 | /path/to/tos/1001 |       5678
```

You can see the full example to play with at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=128a053b978390d976856569154a8de4)*

---

You *always* want to use relationships, and `JOIN`, and *not repeat*. This is formally called [*Normalizing your database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Of course, all rules tend to have exceptions. Having *denormalized* data is left to a few specific cases (normally, data which is *read only*, and where a need for speed is of the utmost concern; this is typical of [*data warehouses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) and for *analytics [(OLAP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)*).

If in doubt: normalize. Always.